Where to find tutorial for Yocto's custom device tree creation?
I am using Ka-ro qs8m-mq00 qsbase2 board. Also I am learning Yocto. I am not an Yocto specialist, I'm just learning this topic, so I have some beginner's troubles.
I faced troubles with SPI and I2C customizing like changes some pins etc. As far as I understand, I need to create my own .dts file that includes existing .dts (in my case imx8mm-qs8m-mq00.dts ?).
Unfortunatelly, I can not find some clear tutorial with this process description. There are some pieces of information about patch files creations, some .bbappend examples etc. But I have not found some step-by-step explanation. It looks like I am near the correct solution, but I can not obtaing image with this customized device tree.
Could you help with this? Could you provide some steps description? Or, probably, there is some clear instruction that I have not found?
So, I created some spitest recipe that will produce image for bitbake spitest-image image generation. This is some "hello, world" C++ application with CMake usage.
Directory structure is as follows:
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── readme.md
└── recipes-spitest
    ├── images
    │   └── spitest-image.bb
    └── spitest
        ├── files
        │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │   ├── main.cpp
        │   └── spitest.dts
        └── spitest_1.0.bb

conf/layer.conf:
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "spitest"
BBFILE_PATTERN_spitest = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_spitest = "6"

LAYERDEPENDS_spitest = "core"
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_spitest = "mickledore"

recipes-spitest/images/spitest-image.bb:
SUMMARY = "spitest image"

require ../../meta-karo-distro/recipes-core/images/karo-image-minimal.bb

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " spitest"

recipes-spitest/spitest/files/spitest.dts
// SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0 OR MIT)
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2019 Lothar Waßmann <LW@KARO-electronics.de>
 *
 */

/dts-v1/;

#include "imx8mm-qs8m-mq00.dts"

/ {
    model = "Ka-Ro electronics QS8M-MQ00 (NXP i.MX8MM) module on QSBASE2 baseboard";

// Some changes
};



recipes-spitest/spitest/spitest_1.0.bb
SUMMARY = "bitbake-layers recipe"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

DESCRIPTION = "This is spitest image."

SRC_URI = "\
    file://CMakeLists.txt \
    file://main.cpp \
    file://spitest.dts \
    "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

KERNEL_DEVICETREE:append = " spitest.dtb"

inherit pkgconfig cmake

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${B}/spitest ${D}${bindir}/spitest
}

I tried to make some error in spitest.dts, but bitbake didn't generate any error message. So, spitest.dts is not compiled and not spitest.dtb generated.
Is it possible neither use patches nor change source dts files?

In order to setup yocto and build an image, the process can be slightly different if you are using a devkit or custom board. As for the devkit, usually a device tree is provided and you only need to modify the image recipe to include your desired packages. However on a custom board, you need to modify/design a custom device-tree that describes your custom hardware. This can be a starting point.
Although your directory structure works, it does not follow yocto style. The follwing is the updated strcture.
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── readme.md
├── recipes-core
│   └── images
│       └── spitest-image.bb
└── recipes-spitest
    └── spitest
        ├── files
        │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │   ├── main.cpp
        │   └── spitest.dts
        └── spitest_1.0.bb

You don't need to provide a dts file together with your spitest program as that is only a user space application. It you want to  modify device tree you can do so by adding it to:
├── recipes-kernel
│   └── linux
│       ├── files
│       │   └── spitest.dts
│       └── linux-imx_%.bbappend

Then you can create a bbappend file for the linux recipe (linux-imx_%.bbappend for example - this has to follow your main linux kernel recipe name) and setup your device-tree.
You can add the following line to your machine configuration of local.conf
KERNEL_DEVICETREE:append = " spitest.dtb"


As far as I understand, I can inherit existing dts, right? How can I do it? I need to create patch for the existing one? Or I can do it in another maneer?
Also could you provde .bbappend file for this case?

You can import a dts file into another to use the nodes it defines, but the general idea is that there is a dtsi file which defines the basic platfomr devices, and then in a dts file you can turn some of the devices off or modify how they should be working and also adding new devices. you can add patch when modifying an exiting dts/dtsi file or you can create a new dts file (recommended if you have a custom design board) this can be brief starting point
